# How to test deployed spring web service containing mongodb database with different database in testing?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, integration-testing

I have a spring rest web service with mongodb database access. I have written some unit tests using spring test and mockmvc. Now I want to test the deployed web service end to end.I will be using Resttemplate for that.
I want to deploy the web service and run the test program. I want to use different test database for testing not the actual database. In the tests, I want to pre populate the database with some entries and rollback that after the tests.
Also this is a shared environment, so multiple users can run tests in parallel but each will run against a different deployed instance. 
I am not able to find a way to do this. I want to run the tests such that each users test run in isolation i.e. they should not refer to the same mongo collection internally. 
How should I go about doing this? Should I create different profiles and how to run the web service under a different profile? or if I use different mongo collection in test than how should I tell the web service to use that collection? 
Any examples will be helpful.

Comment: so many questions. For functional test cases. I prefer DbUnit http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/ , and for embedded database H2 or HSQLDB